# U-SQL Json Extractor is only pulling one record

Tags: json, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm testing data lake for an application I am developing. I'm new to U-SQL and data lake and am just trying to query all records in a JSON file. Right now, It's only returning one record and I'm not sure why because the file has about 200.

My code is:

```
DECLARE @input string = @"/MSEStream/output/2016/08/12_0_fc829ede3c1d4cf9a3278d43e7e4e9d0.json";

REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];


@allposts = 
EXTRACT 
    id  string
FROM @input 
USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

@result =
SELECT *
FROM @allposts;

OUTPUT  @result
TO  "/ProcessedQueries/all_posts.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Data Example:

```
{
"id":"398507",
"contenttype":"POST",
"posttype":"post",
"uri":"http://twitter.com/etc",
"title":null,
"profile":{
   "@class":"PublisherV2_0",
   "name":"Company",
   "id":"2163171",
   "profileIcon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/image",
   "profileLocation":{
      "@class":"DocumentLocation",
      "locality":"Toronto",
      "adminDistrict":"ON",
      "countryRegion":"Canada",
      "coordinates":{
         "latitude":43.7217,
         "longitude":-31.432},
         "quadKey":"000000000000000"},
      "displayName":"Name",
      "externalId":"00000000000"},
   "source":{
       "name":"blogs",
       "id":"18",
       "param":"Twitter"},
   "content":{
       "text":"Description of post"},
       "language":{
           "name":"English",
           "code":"en"},
       "abstracttext":"More Text and links",
       "score":{}
   }
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JsonExtractor takes an argument that allows you to specify which items or objects are being mapped into rows using a JSON Path expression. If you don’t specify anything it will take the top root (which is one row).

You want every one of the items in the array, so you specify it as:

USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor("[*]");

Where [*] is the JSON Path expression that says give me all the elements of the array which in this case is the top-level array.

Comment: When I put in that It returns nothing. I add an example of the data I'm pulling in the post.

Comment: I figured out what was happening, the output file is a line separated file. Is there a way to read it like that or do I need to have it formatted as an array?

Comment: You can either write your own extractor that does the line per line processing by extending the current JSONExtractor (take a look at some of the other extractors on our GitHub at http://usql.io), or you can use a built-in extractor and read the JSON out as a string (max length is 128kB then). An example is here https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats/readme.md

Answer (score 1):

If you have a JSON node in your field called id, your original script posted in the question would return the node with name "id" under the rootnode. To get all the nodes, your script will be structured as

```
@allposts = 
EXTRACT 
    id  string,
    contenttype string,
    posttype string,
    uri string,
    title string,
    profile string
FROM @input 
USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();
```

Please let us know if it works. The alternative would be to extract it using a native extractor to read it all in a string (as MRys mentioned, as long as your JSON is under 128 KB this would work).

```
@allposts = 
EXTRACT
   json string
FROM @input
USING Extractors.Text(delimiter:'\b', quoting:false);
```

Comment: `Extractors.Csv` doesn't allow delimiters.

Comment: Can you try using Extractors.Text instead please with the same syntax?